# When and by whom was Deadman Wonderland created?

Tags: deadman-wonderland

There's a couple of contradictions.

I'm reading that Tamaki created it after he lost his games in the Earthquake.  And he created Carnival Corpse for fun.

I'm also reading that Hagire Rinichiro created it after the earthquake and after taking over the old man's body.  That old man was supposed to be the previous winner of Carnival Corpse but how is that possible if Carnival Corpse was only created after Hagire took over the old man's body?

Then there's the question of when he took over Toto's body.  In the later chapters (50+) it shows Toto with his original personality and his original clothes (with the vest and pants instead of the gown he wears now) asking why he's not fighting the Wretched Egg and Hagire telling him he's going to take over his body.

But the first time we see Toto during Ganta's time in DW, he seems to have switched over his clothes and personality (wearing the gown) already.  We also see old man Hagire talking with Shiro.

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems there are 2 unrelated questions asked here: "Who & when was Deadman Wonderland created?" (the title), and "When did Hagire take over Toto's body?" (the question body). If they're related, could you explain the relation with the original question? Otherwise, please post it as separate question.

Comment: @AkiTanaka If Hagire created Deadman Wonderland, at what point did he take over the old man's body and subsequently Toto's body? There's a contradiction because the old man and Toto were supposed to be Carnival Corpse (the game inside DW) winners.  One of the flashbacks show Hagire as the old man saying he wants to create Deadman Wonderland.  So which came first? And the migration from Old Man to Toto is a mystery because it might explain the previous question.  During the migration, is his consciousness in both bodies for a period of time (ie in Hagire Original and Old man, Old man and Toto)?